# plotting google map markers using an array

Tags: javascript, google-maps, plot

i need some help with google map api v3 markers.

I got an array which contains coordinates i retrieve from a file. I am trying to traverse the array, and plot them using the markers.

Traversing the array to retrieve the coordinates is not a problem, however, when i start using the coordinates to plot on google map. i realise that i am getting (NaN, NaN) as the coordinates.. Because of this, i am not able to do the plotting.. any idea why isit? Thanksss

my codes so far:

```
   var temp = new google.maps.LatLng(myObject[o]);
   retrieverouteMarker(temp);
```

Comment: put some more code, the one where u actually get the coordinates and create google.maps.Marker() object. you must be doing something wrong with parsing/retrieving of coordinates values.

Comment: do not have the codes with me now.. but by tomorrow i will add it in. btw from what i read online, they say that lat lng, take in only the object and i am parsing in a string. 

When i alert "myObject[o]", i manage to get the lat and lng. But i just can not parse it in..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [constructor for LatLng](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#LatLng) takes two arguments (the latitude and longitude of the point), so this line is clearly wrong:

```
var temp = new google.maps.LatLng(myObject[o]);
```

Of course, since we have to idea what `myObject` is, or what the function `retrieverouteMarker` does, there isn't much more we can do to help.

Comment: yea got it.. myObject actually contains lat and lng in one single string. I manage to solve it by splitting up myObject into two different string containing lat and lng respectively:)